# Force fontconfig use specific font for given glyphs

Tags: fonts, fontconfig, i3

Is it possible? I use i3bar status line and want it to display some unicode glyphs, but some of them cause the whole text be vertically misaligned and thus cropped:

[image]

In this particular example the speaker glyph causes this. How do I force fontconfig use a different font for it? The font in the bar is Terminus, the glyph is displayed with Noto Sans Symbols2 (seems it's the default fallback).
I'm pretty sure it's due to the fonts, because on my other machine the symbols is drawn with another font (Segoe UI Emoji) and no misalignment appears. I've tried this in my `.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`:

```
<alias>                                                                                                        
  <family>Noto Sans Symbols2</family>                                                
  <prefer>                                                                 
    <family>Segoe UI Emoji</family>                                            
  </prefer>                                                                
</alias>
```

But it didn't work.